# Does this make sense with defer cancel()?

Tags: go

In a `http.HandlerFunc` I got this. But my question is: Does it make sense to put `defer cancel()` after the timeout context is applied?

Because the select in the bottom will continue listening until the context is done. And the defer will be executed AFTER the context is done. But then it is already done? :)

```
//  Apply timeout context
var cancel context.CancelFunc
ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Duration(time.Duration(match_route.timeout) * time.Second))
defer cancel() // <--- does this make sense

go func(){
    match_route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    cancel()
}()

select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
        http.Error(w, "Timeout", http.StatusRequestTimeout)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it does make sense, actually the purpose of using `defer cancel()` is to ensure that the cancel function is called to release resources associated with the context, regardless of how the function exits, in your example, `cancel()` function is deferred to be executed after the `http.HandlerFunc` completes or when the context is done,so `go func()` is responsible for executing the `match_route.handler` function with the provided context and then calling `cancel()` to explicitly cancel the context,and `select` statement is used to wait for the context to be done, and if the context is done due to a deadline exceeded, it will return an error response!